# Page break in rdlc report with Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

I created RDLC report which contains `n` number of rows. I just need to use page break with a specific condition.  For example, I have Bin values `1,2,3`. Each bin has specific number of rows, (i.e `Bin 1 = 10rows, 2 - 5rows`). I just want to show each bin in single page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have a group based on `Bin` - you may already have one.

In the `Bin` group properties, make sure **Page Breaks** -> **Page break options** is set to `Between each instance of a group`:

[image]

Comment: iam also looking for the same (page break according to condition),this could not be suitable for to add conditions